# how can I get data in item stored when entering data from filtering listview?

Tags: android, listview, filtering

The thing is I can get data stored in item when I select an item, type something in EditText and click on the ImageButton next to it:[Selecting item and typing some data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f7Ch.png)

[After clicking on ImageButton data is stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqfmV.png)

When I filter some fields to enter some data, happens the following:

[Data stored in filtered listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37sBU.png)

The data is stored but when I close the searchview the data disappears:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN8Sg.png)

So, what I want is the data get stored completely when I close the searchview.

The code is the following:

This is the Fragment:

```
public class CrearProductoFragment extends Fragment {

    String[] columnas;
    String registros;
    EditText etInsertarProd;
    ImageButton insertarProd;
    TextView camposNuevoProd, datosNuevoProd;
    ListView lvNuevoProd;
    Button btInsertarProd;
    static DatosProductoAdapter productoAdapter;
    int posicion;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crear_producto, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        columnas = bundle.getStringArray("columnas");
        registros = "";

        etInsertarProd = view.findViewById(R.id.etInsertarProd);
        insertarProd = view.findViewById(R.id.insertarProd);
        insertarProd.setEnabled(false);
        insertarProd.setClickable(false);
        camposNuevoProd = view.findViewById(R.id.camposNuevoProd);
        camposNuevoProd.setText("Campos");
        datosNuevoProd = view.findViewById(R.id.datosNuevoProd);
        datosNuevoProd.setText("Datos del Registro");
        lvNuevoProd = view.findViewById(R.id.lvNuevoProd);

        btInsertarProd = view.findViewById(R.id.btInsertarProd);

        // crear arraylist de tipo registros (crear un getDatos)
        final ArrayList<Registros> listaCampos = getCampos();

        // crear instancia del adaptador
        productoAdapter = new DatosProductoAdapter(getContext(), listaCampos);

        // asignar el adaptador al listview
        lvNuevoProd.setAdapter(productoAdapter);

        insertarProd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // capturar texto escrito en edittext
                String texto = etInsertarProd.getText().toString();

                //capturar el campo seleccionado en el listview y asignarle el texto
                for (int i = 0; i < lvNuevoProd.getCount(); i++) {
                    if (i == posicion) {
                        ((Registros) lvNuevoProd.getItemAtPosition(posicion)).setRegistro(texto);
                    }
                }

                productoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                etInsertarProd.setText("");
                insertarProd.setEnabled(false);
                insertarProd.setClickable(false);
                etInsertarProd.clearFocus();
                insertarProd.setAlpha(0.4f);
            }

            //crear objeto Registros e insertarlo en el campo seleccionado

            //

            //int indice = lvNuevoProd.getSelectedItemPosition()-1;
            //View view1 =  productoAdapter.getView(indice,view,lvNuevoProd);
            //Registros registro = (Registros) productoAdapter.getItem(indice);
            //registro.setRegistro(texto);
            //for (int cam = 0; cam < getCampos().size(); cam++){
            //crearProductoAdapter.glvNuevoProd.getSelectedItem() etInsertarProd.getText()
            //if () {
            //  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Selecciona algún campo para introducir datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //}
            //}

        });

        lvNuevoProd.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                view.setSelected(true);
                insertarProd.setAlpha(1.0f);
                insertarProd.setEnabled(true);
                insertarProd.setClickable(true);
                etInsertarProd.requestFocus();
                //registro = (Registros) productoAdapter.getItem(position);
                posicion = position;
                //view.findViewById(R.id.llRegistro).setSelected(true);
            }

        });


        btInsertarProd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String cadena = "";
                boolean seleccionado = false;
                for (int cam = 0; cam < getCampos().size(); cam++) {
                    cadena = cadena + getCampos().get(cam).getRegistro();
                }
                if (cadena.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Campos vacíos: introduce algún dato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    private ArrayList<Registros> getCampos() {

        ArrayList<Registros> listaCampos = new ArrayList<>();
        Registros r;
        for (int cam = 0; cam < columnas.length; cam++) {
            r = new Registros(columnas[cam], registros);
            listaCampos.add(r);
        }
        return listaCampos;
    }

    public void buscarCampo(String consulta) {
        productoAdapter.getFilter().filter(consulta);
    }

}
```

This is the Adapter:

```
public class DatosProductoAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Registros> listaRegistros, filtradosRegistros, filters;
    CustomFilter customFilter;

    public DatosProductoAdapter() {
    }

    public DatosProductoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Registros> listaRegistros) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listaRegistros = listaRegistros;
        this.filtradosRegistros = listaRegistros;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listaRegistros.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listaRegistros.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(this.context, R.layout.datos_producto_view, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvCamps = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCamps);
            viewHolder.tvRegs = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvRegs);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tvCamps.setText(listaRegistros.get(position).getCampo());
        viewHolder.tvRegs.setText(listaRegistros.get(position).getRegistro());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvCamps, tvRegs;
    }

    public ArrayList<Registros> getFilters() {
        return filters;
    }

    public ArrayList<Registros> getListaRegistros() {
        return listaRegistros;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (customFilter == null) {
            customFilter = new CustomFilter();
        }
        return customFilter;
    }

    class CustomFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected Filter.FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            Filter.FilterResults results = new Filter.FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                filters = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < filtradosRegistros.size(); i++) {
                    if (filtradosRegistros.get(i).getCampo().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        Registros registros = new Registros(filtradosRegistros.get(i).getCampo(), filtradosRegistros.get(i).getRegistro());
                        filters.add(registros);
                    }
                }
                results.values = filters;
                results.count = filters.size();

            } else {
                results.values = filtradosRegistros;
                results.count = filtradosRegistros.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
            listaRegistros = (ArrayList<Registros>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, the name of the Adapter has nothing to do with the name of the Fragment, but it's becuase it is commun for several fragments.

I'm new in android and I've spent many hours trying to solve it, so help is welcomed and really appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: * Sorry, when searview is closed or search is erased, (as you can see in the image), the data dissapear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:-

CrearProductoFragment.java:

```
public class CrearProductoFragment extends Fragment {

String[] columnas;
String registros;
EditText etInsertarProd;
ImageButton insertarProd;
TextView camposNuevoProd, datosNuevoProd;
ListView lvNuevoProd;
Button btInsertarProd;
static DatosProductoAdapter productoAdapter;
int posicion;

ArrayList<Registros> listaCampos = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crear_producto, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    columnas = bundle.getStringArray("columnas");
    registros = "";

    etInsertarProd = view.findViewById(R.id.etInsertarProd);
    insertarProd = view.findViewById(R.id.insertarProd);
    insertarProd.setEnabled(false);
    insertarProd.setClickable(false);
    camposNuevoProd = view.findViewById(R.id.camposNuevoProd);
    camposNuevoProd.setText("Campos");
    datosNuevoProd = view.findViewById(R.id.datosNuevoProd);
    datosNuevoProd.setText("Datos del Registro");
    lvNuevoProd = view.findViewById(R.id.lvNuevoProd);

    btInsertarProd = view.findViewById(R.id.btInsertarProd);

    // crear arraylist de tipo registros (crear un getDatos)
    listaCampos = getCampos();

    // crear instancia del adaptador
    productoAdapter = new DatosProductoAdapter(getContext(), listaCampos);

    // asignar el adaptador al listview
    lvNuevoProd.setAdapter(productoAdapter);


    insertarProd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // capturar texto escrito en edittext
            String texto = etInsertarProd.getText().toString();

            //capturar el campo seleccionado en el listview y asignarle el texto
            Registros registro = listaCampos.get(posicion);
            registro.setRegistro(texto);

            productoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            etInsertarProd.setText("");
            insertarProd.setEnabled(false);
            insertarProd.setClickable(false);
            etInsertarProd.clearFocus();
            insertarProd.setAlpha(0.4f);
        }

        //crear objeto Registros e insertarlo en el campo seleccionado

        //

        //int indice = lvNuevoProd.getSelectedItemPosition()-1;
        //View view1 =  productoAdapter.getView(indice,view,lvNuevoProd);
        //Registros registro = (Registros) productoAdapter.getItem(indice);
        //registro.setRegistro(texto);
        //for (int cam = 0; cam < getCampos().size(); cam++){
        //crearProductoAdapter.glvNuevoProd.getSelectedItem() etInsertarProd.getText()
        //if () {
        //  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Selecciona algún campo para introducir datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //}
        //}

    });

    lvNuevoProd.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            view.setSelected(true);
            insertarProd.setAlpha(1.0f);
            insertarProd.setEnabled(true);
            insertarProd.setClickable(true);
            etInsertarProd.requestFocus();
            //registro = (Registros) productoAdapter.getItem(position);
            posicion = productoAdapter.getItem(position);
            //view.findViewById(R.id.llRegistro).setSelected(true);
        }

    });

    btInsertarProd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String cadena = "";
            boolean seleccionado = false;
            for (int cam = 0; cam < getCampos().size(); cam++) {
                cadena = cadena + getCampos().get(cam).getRegistro();
            }
            if (cadena.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Campos vacíos: introduce algún dato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}

private ArrayList<Registros> getCampos() {
    ArrayList<Registros> listaCampos = new ArrayList<>();

    Registros r;
    for (int cam = 0; cam < columnas.length; cam++) {
        r = new Registros(columnas[cam], registros);
        listaCampos.add(r);
    }
    return listaCampos;
}

public void buscarCampo(String consulta) {
    productoAdapter.getFilter().filter(consulta);
}

}
```

DatosProductoAdapter.java:

```
public class DatosProductoAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
Context context;
ArrayList<Registros> listaRegistros;
ArrayList<Integer> listIndex = new ArrayList<>();
CustomFilter customFilter;

public DatosProductoAdapter() {
}

public DatosProductoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Registros> listaRegistros) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listaRegistros = listaRegistros;
    resetIndex();
}

public void resetIndex() {
    listIndex.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < listaRegistros.size(); i++) listIndex.add(i);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listIndex.size();
}

@Override
public Integer getItem(int position) {
    return listIndex.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(this.context, R.layout.datos_producto_view, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvCamps = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCamps);
        viewHolder.tvRegs = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvRegs);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.tvCamps.setText(listaRegistros.get(getItem(position)).getCampo());
    viewHolder.tvRegs.setText(listaRegistros.get(getItem(position)).getRegistro());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvCamps, tvRegs;
}

//public ArrayList<Registros> getFilters() {
//    return filters;
//}

public ArrayList<Registros> getListaRegistros() {
    return listaRegistros;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (customFilter == null) {
        customFilter = new CustomFilter();
    }
    return customFilter;
}

class CustomFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected Filter.FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            listIndex.clear();
            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < listaRegistros.size(); i++) {
                if (listaRegistros.get(i).getCampo().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                    listIndex.add(i);
                }
            }
        } else {
            resetIndex();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been working in another part of the project. I must say that your solution works really good. Thank you very much!